# update array inside object inside another array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

this is my reducer

```
let initialState = [
  { name: 'john', messages: [{ message: "hi" }] },
  { name: 'max', messages: [{ message: "howdy" }] },
  { name: 'alex', messages: [{ message: "hello" }] },
  ...
];

const Messages = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MESSAGES":
      return [...state, ...action.payload];
    case "UPDATE_ALEX_MESSAGES":
      // HOW TO UPDATE????
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Messages;
```

how to update alex's messages and push another object to it? (commented part of the above code)

**Note**:
alex's position is not stable and it may change. so something like `state[2]` is not what I'm looking for. Something more like `state.find(x => x.name === 'alex')` is more like it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` method and the spread syntax can help you achieve the desired result.

Using the `map()` method, iterate over the state array and inside the callback function, check if the current user object's `name` is "alex", if it is, update the current object's `messages` property by assigning a new array to it and using the spread syntax to copy the existing messages and then also add the new message in the array.

```
case "UPDATE_ALEX_MESSAGES":
  return state.map((user) => {
      if (name === "alex") {
         user.messages = [...user.messages, newMessage];
      }

      return user;
  });
```

You could also avoid mutating the existing object by returning a new object inside the `if` block.

```
case "UPDATE_ALEX_MESSAGES":
  return state.map((user) => {
      if (name === "alex") {
         return { ...user, messages: [...user.messages, newMessage] };
      }

      return user;
  });
```

Ideally, you would pass the name of the user in the payload of the action, so the following condition

```
if (name === "alex") { .. }
```

will become

```
if (name === action.payload) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this npm package to solve this problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer. It is a super useful tool that helps reduce boilerplate code